# need to focus on the first control in DOM Tree which has error, using knockout-validation

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, knockout-validation

I am validating an HTML using knockout-validation, I need to focus the cursor on the first control having error how could I do that?

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: I've attempted to answer but it's a bit tricky to know what you may have tried already unsuccessfully if you don't add that info to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are setting an error class for your elements in the `data-bind` attrbute of all elements being validated:

```
data-bind = " ...
              validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }
              ... "
```

Then at the point of validation you can get all of these elements with jquery and just apply focus to the first one:

```
$(".input-validation-error").first().focus();
```